# Nautilus slow and finally crashes

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, nautilus

I migrated my laptop in 14.04.1 LTS (from a 12.04 partially upgraded in 13.10 for hardware support). Since then I have randomly very slow nautilus windows opening. When that happen, if a nautilus window is opened it become grey and the icons on the desktop are frozen the time for the new nautilus window to show up.

I thought problem solve by editing .gtk-bookmarks in home directory witch contained some old reference to unavailable samba shares. But the problem arise again and I get some random crashes.

I tried to launch nautilus from command line but no message.

Do you have an idea ?

Here is an extract of the crash report :

`ProblemType: Crash
Architecture: amd64
CurrentDesktop: Unity
Date: Thu Sep 25 14:26:00 2014
DistroRelease: Ubuntu 14.04
ExecutablePath: /usr/bin/nautilus
ExecutableTimestamp: 1405434801
ProcCmdline: nautilus -n
ProcCwd: /home/pro
ProcEnviron:
LANGUAGE=fr_FR
PATH=(custom, user)
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=
LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8
SHELL=/bin/bash
ProcMaps:
00400000-00552000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 8264348                            /usr/bin/nautilus
00752000-00753000 r--p 00152000 08:03 8264348                            /usr/bin/nautilus
00753000-00758000 rw-p 00153000 08:03 8264348                            /usr/bin/nautilus
00758000-00759000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
02706000-03377000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7f6da8db1000-7f6dac000000 r--p 00000000 08:03 9699498                    /usr/share/icons/hicolor/icon-theme.cache
[...]
ProcStatus:
Name:    nautilus
State:    S (sleeping)
Tgid:    3097
Ngid:    0
Pid:    3097
PPid:    2807
TracerPid:    0
Uid:    1000    1000    1000    1000
Gid:    1000    1000    1000    1000
FDSize:    64
Groups:    4 24 27 30 46 109 124 125 1000
VmPeak:     1488640 kB
VmSize:     1414324 kB
VmLck:           0 kB
VmPin:           0 kB
VmHWM:       90388 kB
VmRSS:       45960 kB
VmData:      924328 kB
VmStk:         136 kB
VmExe:        1352 kB
VmLib:       63352 kB
VmPTE:         916 kB
VmSwap:         320 kB
Threads:    4
SigQ:    0/26789
SigPnd:    0000000000000000
ShdPnd:    0000000000000000
SigBlk:    0000000000000000
SigIgn:    0000000000001000
SigCgt:    0000000180000000
CapInh:    0000000000000000
CapPrm:    0000000000000000
CapEff:    0000000000000000
CapBnd:    0000001fffffffff
Seccomp:    0
Cpus_allowed:    f
Cpus_allowed_list:    0-3
Mems_allowed:    00000000,00000001
Mems_allowed_list:    0
voluntary_ctxt_switches:    13077
nonvoluntary_ctxt_switches:    3114
Signal: 11
Uname: Linux 3.13.0-35-generic x86_64
UserGroups: adm cdrom dip lpadmin plugdev sambashare sudo vboxusers
_LogindSession: /user/1000.user/c2.session`

Comment: Well, seems that this file (.gtk-bookmarks) is no longer used, so that was why it was refering to old shares. The new one ~/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks has no reference to unavailable shares.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS for about 6 months and have the problem since the begining - clean system, HP Probook 450. The solution for the slow responding / crashing Nautilus was to delete all the bookmarks (Menu/Bookmarks); the problem did not occurred after. Unfortunately can not confirm if that's a global solution.

Answer (score 0):

I can make one observation, even if it might not be the ideal solution for you.  It has been my repeated observation, and that of several friends, that various 64bit distros of Ubuntu didn't seem particularly stable.  We have all settled for using 32bit distros of Ubuntu on our 64 bit hardware.

I've only rarely had issues with Nautilus being slow or unresponsive.  In all cases the cause was traced to using poor quality USB memory sticks, which isn't something I do particularly often, but I'm often asked to perform data recovery, and sometimes such drives are provided to me as recovery media.  Are you entirely certain your drive is healthy?  You might try opening Disk Utility and find out if it has bad news for you.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I didn't think about a disk failure but in my case Disk Utility says my disk is healthy (SSD drive on Asus UX31A).

Answer (score 0):

I have this too, and this is probably because you have bookmarked a network drive, the fact you mention previously using Samba is very telling. Nautilus seems to want to secure "a network touch" in the "Window Renderer Thread" for every bookmarked device before it renders the window to the desktop environment - not only is this suboptimal, but also it means that it's hard to diagnose/remove misconfiguration smb: connections from the past.

In terms of recommending how to fix it you are doing all the right things and have probably followed the right thought processes

Answer (score 0):

I emptied the Template folder and Nautilus works again like a charm. If you put a lot of files into it, then Nautilus will try to make a "New" option for all the files you have in there.